# Search in database and echo result

Tags: php, mysql, database, search

I'm having a problem with this search, the error is Call to a member function query() on a non-object in /data/web/virtuals/81877/virtual/www/subdom/hdb/page_search.php on line 8

**

```
    if(!empty($_GET["search"]) AND isset($_GET["search"]))
    {
      $search = $_GET["search"];
      $query= "SELECT * FROM tblSKUPINA WHERE CONCAT_WS(' ',NAZEV,ZANR) LIKE  '%$search%'";
      $user = $pdo->query($query);
      while($user_final = $user->fetch())
      {                       
        echo "
          <DIV class='text_search'>
            <A href='profil?profile=".$user_final["ID_OSOBA"]."'>"
                .$user_final["JMENO"]." ".$user_final["PRIJMENI"].
            "</A>
        ";

        }
        }

?>**
```

Comment: you should specify line numbers, we don't know which is line 8

Comment: if it is  $user = $pdo->query($query); then $pdo could be null

Comment: i didn't declare pdo, begginer's mistake

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have a [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php) connection before your query:

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass);
```

Or if it is in external file then you have to include that file and have to use `global $pdo` to access the object like:

```
// Hold the connection
include `db_config.php`
global $pdo;
```

Comment: His `$pdo` is prolly false due to a failed connection

Comment: oh my god i totally forgot about this. begginer's fail. anyway thank you very much, it ain't workin but at least it isn't throwing any errors :D